# Is there a way to enable autocompletion for PyQt5 with Eclipse Kepler and PyDev 2.8?

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, osx-mavericks, pyqt5

it seems I can't find a way to enable autocompletion for PyQt5 in Eclipse using PyDev 2.8. I'm running Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks.

While installing PyQt5 I noticed that there weren't '.py' modules installed in the default library paths for PyQt5 but only '.sip' files. Can this be the cause of the problem? If yes, does exist a workaround?

Example:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
QA #here I'd expect QApplication appear as suggestion but it doesn't
```

Note: this is just an example. Autocompletion does not show any of the modules, classes, method, functions or whatever from PyQt5.

The following is the value of the PYTHONPATH variable:

```
macbookpro:~ giovanni$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

And here the listing of files and dirs there:

```
macbookpro:site-packages giovanni$ ls -haltR
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   26 root  wheel   884B  6 Dic 12:51 PyQt5
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel   102B  6 Dic 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x  649 root  wheel    22K  6 Dic 12:51 ..

./PyQt5:
total 36408
drwxr-xr-x  26 root  wheel   884B  6 Dic 12:51 .
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    12K  6 Dic 12:51 Qt.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   440K  6 Dic 12:51 QtDesigner.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   207K  6 Dic 12:51 QtXmlPatterns.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   280K  6 Dic 12:51 _QOpenGLFunctions_2_0.so
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   826B  6 Dic 12:51 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 root  wheel   510B  6 Dic 12:51 uic
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    95K  6 Dic 12:51 QtSerialPort.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   379K  6 Dic 12:51 QtSql.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   128K  6 Dic 12:51 QtSvg.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   116K  6 Dic 12:51 QtTest.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   211K  6 Dic 12:51 QtWebKit.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   358K  6 Dic 12:51 QtWebKitWidgets.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   5,8M  6 Dic 12:51 QtWidgets.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   729K  6 Dic 12:51 QtMultimedia.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   137K  6 Dic 12:51 QtMultimediaWidgets.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   861K  6 Dic 12:51 QtNetwork.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   153K  6 Dic 12:51 QtOpenGL.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   266K  6 Dic 12:51 QtPrintSupport.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   595K  6 Dic 12:51 QtQml.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   920K  6 Dic 12:51 QtQuick.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   327K  6 Dic 12:51 QtSensors.so
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   102B  6 Dic 12:51 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   2,7M  6 Dic 12:51 QtCore.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   3,0M  6 Dic 12:51 QtGui.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   148K  6 Dic 12:51 QtHelp.so

./PyQt5/uic:
total 200
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 root  wheel   510B  6 Dic 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 root  wheel   884B  6 Dic 12:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x@  9 root  wheel   306B  6 Dic 12:51 Compiler
drwxr-xr-x@  5 root  wheel   170B  6 Dic 12:51 Loader
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   8,5K  6 Dic 12:51 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   4,0K  6 Dic 12:51 driver.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   2,1K  6 Dic 12:51 exceptions.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   5,0K  6 Dic 12:51 icon_cache.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   5,3K  6 Dic 12:51 objcreator.py
drwxr-xr-x@  9 root  wheel   306B  6 Dic 12:51 port_v2
drwxr-xr-x@  9 root  wheel   306B  6 Dic 12:51 port_v3
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel    18K  6 Dic 12:51 properties.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   2,7K  6 Dic 12:51 pyuic.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel    35K  6 Dic 12:51 uiparser.py
drwxr-xr-x@  7 root  wheel   238B  6 Dic 12:51 widget-plugins

./PyQt5/uic/Compiler:
total 104
drwxr-xr-x@  9 root  wheel   306B  6 Dic 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 root  wheel   510B  6 Dic 12:51 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,0K  6 Dic 12:51 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   4,4K  6 Dic 12:51 compiler.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   2,7K  6 Dic 12:51 indenter.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   2,5K  6 Dic 12:51 misc.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   4,2K  6 Dic 12:51 proxy_metaclass.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   5,5K  6 Dic 12:51 qobjectcreator.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel    16K  6 Dic 12:51 qtproxies.py

./PyQt5/uic/Loader:
total 32
drwxr-xr-x@  5 root  wheel   170B  6 Dic 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 root  wheel   510B  6 Dic 12:51 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,0K  6 Dic 12:51 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   3,0K  6 Dic 12:51 loader.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   4,9K  6 Dic 12:51 qobjectcreator.py

./PyQt5/uic/port_v2:
total 56
drwxr-xr-x@  9 root  wheel   306B  6 Dic 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 root  wheel   510B  6 Dic 12:51 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,0K  6 Dic 12:51 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,4K  6 Dic 12:51 as_string.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,3K  6 Dic 12:51 ascii_upper.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,5K  6 Dic 12:51 invoke.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,5K  6 Dic 12:51 load_plugin.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,2K  6 Dic 12:51 proxy_base.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,1K  6 Dic 12:51 string_io.py

./PyQt5/uic/port_v3:
total 56
drwxr-xr-x@  9 root  wheel   306B  6 Dic 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 root  wheel   510B  6 Dic 12:51 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,0K  6 Dic 12:51 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,4K  6 Dic 12:51 as_string.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,3K  6 Dic 12:51 ascii_upper.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,5K  6 Dic 12:51 invoke.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,5K  6 Dic 12:51 load_plugin.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,2K  6 Dic 12:51 proxy_base.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,0K  6 Dic 12:51 string_io.py

./PyQt5/uic/widget-plugins:
total 40
drwxr-xr-x@  7 root  wheel   238B  6 Dic 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 root  wheel   510B  6 Dic 12:51 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,5K  6 Dic 12:51 qaxcontainer.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,5K  6 Dic 12:51 qscintilla.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,5K  6 Dic 12:51 qtdeclarative.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   1,6K  6 Dic 12:51 qtprintsupport.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   2,4K  6 Dic 12:51 qtwebkit.py
```

Comment: Can you give an example on what exactly is not autocompleting? (provided that things are properly in the PYTHONPATH, things should work by default)

Comment: @FabioZadrozny I've edited the question as you required. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found PySide which is a binding to the QT libraries. It's released under the MIT license and work well in tandem with PyDev 2.8 and Eclipse Kepler on Mac OS 10.9.3.

Comment: Mind that PySide does not work with python3 (yet - but there are no real plans to switch) - which is bad™.

Answer (score 1):

It seems things are in place... PyDev 2.8.x did have some issues on setting the PYTHONPATH when things changed, so, ideally, please try the nightly build (see: http://pydev.org/download.html for details on getting it) and see if it fixes things for you.

Note that on PyDev 3.x you need to point Eclipse to use a Java 7 JVM (some users seem to have issues on making Eclipse use it the proper java vm, especially on Mac OS -- if you have this problem, maybe you can check LiClipse 0.9.0 -- which is mostly a distribution of PyDev standalone + some other niceties + a way to directly support PyDev -- and it has PyDev 3 builtin -- otherwise, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20477000/110451 for instructions on how to configure it).

Comment: Thank you for your response and for your time. I tried the LiCplise approach but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Humm, one more thing to check: did you try adding 'PyQt5' -- and maybe even 'PyQt5.QtCore' to the forced builtins? (see http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for details on that).

Comment: Also, did you check if /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages is in the paths in the preferences > pydev > interpreters > python interpreter > libraries?