# Installing PyDev into Eclipse on Mac Mavericks

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, pydev, osx-mavericks

Mavericks on Macbook Pro. with 8 Gig.  When trying to install the PyDev 3.0 IDE into new Eclipse install (with latest versions Python 3.3.3, Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1 Build id: 20130919-0819), PyDev does not show in Eclipse preferences, so it cannot create Python project. I have Android Developer Tools installed and works fine. I don't know if that's interfering with the install because the ADT uses a different Eclipse install.  Any solutions to this problem?  Been 3 hours into this with no luck.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

The usual problem is that PyDev now requires java 7... not having java 7 makes Eclipse simply not show PyDev.

Note that even if you have java 7 installed it's possible that you're still using an older version of java.

To check if Eclipse is using java 7 check the about > installation details > configuration (see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example for details on how to specify the vm).

Comment: Already running Java 7 VM, but no joy.  I did receive a tip to try out LiClipse.  I downloaded and installed to find PyDev already in preferences!  A welcome site!  Here's the reply that I followed:

Note: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ has a PyDev standalone version which has a bundled jre which should make the process much smoother...

Comment: Nice :)  LiClipse is really a standalone of PyDev + some other goodies and does streamline a bunch of things, and the support given to it goes directly into the development of PyDev itself!

Answer (score 2):

I just went through this. My mistake was I was installed Java 7 JRE and not JDK. Downloaded and installed the JDK and  everything was groovy. 
JDK - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Answer (score 0):

Already running Java 7 VM, but no joy.  I did receive a tip to try out LiClipse.  I downloaded and installed to find PyDev already in preferences!  A welcome site!  Here's the reply that I followed:

Note: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ has a PyDev standalone version which has a bundled jre which should make the process much smoother...